# Corrupted certificate: Missing Private Key

Tags: macos, certificate, ios-app-signing

All,

I am a first time iMac user. Yesterday I installed Flutter.

I used my iCloud ID to create app signing, as I am only interested in experimenting with my iPhone.

By fooling around by trying to fix another issue ("Codesign wants to access key 'access' in your keychain"), I deleted my Xcode certificate. The net result is that I can neither recover nor re-create the certificate.

How can I fix this issue? Many of the StackOverflow related posts don't appear to apply to me as I don't have a developer account and I am not interested in distribution

I am using Mojave 10.14.6, Xcode 11.3.1

[image]

Comment: Do you have a backup from when the private key was in your keychain? If not, you need to start over and create a new key and certificate.

Comment: @Gordon - That is the problem. I don't know how do it. All I did in Xcode was go to Signing and enter my iCloud ID and password. How do I repeat the process from scratch? What do I delete and where?

Answer (score 0):

I see you commented, but have you actually opened the keychain app? most of the settings for Mac is, once the application is selected, in the upper left of the screen there are preferences and options in the keychain app to delete the keychain, which would allow a fresh start. Keychain can break easily in my experience

Comment: thank you ... Yes I did indeed open the keychain app and deleted the certificate ... In any case, a lot of new firmware updates and install, everything seems to be working again ...

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working ...

1. I decided to check for firmware updates, and the Mac updated from Mojave to Catalina. For reasons I don't understand, but won't complain about, that fixed the certificate issue. The certificate was automatically regenerated/fixed (?) and Xcode stopped complaining
2. Using Xcode, I then tried to install the app on my iPhone. I had the following error [dyld: Library not loaded](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051) which apparently was due to the fact that I was using a non-developer ID. The post recommended upgrading the iPhone to iOS 13.4.
3. Once I did that, however, Xcode (on the laptop) was out of sync with the iPhone. I upgraded Xcode to the latest version
4. Xcode successfully managed to install the app on my iPhone
5. Flutter successfully managed to install the app on my iPhone.

@Daniel and @Gordon, thank you for your assistance